# Running an .exe from CMD and automatically passing arguments to it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmd

I was trying to make a custom command but it's not working as it's supposed to.
My file is called hello.exe and it's located in a `C:\` folder added to `PATH`. This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My intentions are to run the executable from CMD like so: `hello Ulisse`, and it should output `Hello, Ulisse!`. However it does not seem to work, when I run the exe I get a black console awaiting for my name to be inputted.
So, is there any way I can get the argument name to be directly passed from CMD to the variable `name`, therefore not having to input the name AFTER you first ran the command?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { std::cout << "Hello, " << argv[1]'; }` . See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen this implemented using argc and argv. Below is a snippet from the following site http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if ( argc != 2 ) // argc should be 2 for correct execution
    // We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name
    cout<<"usage: "<< argv[0] <<" <filename>\n";
  else {
    // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
    ifstream the_file ( argv[1] );
    // Always check to see if file opening succeeded
    if ( !the_file.is_open() )
      cout<<"Could not open file\n";
    else {
      char x;
      // the_file.get ( x ) returns false if the end of the file
      //  is reached or an error occurs
      while ( the_file.get ( x ) )
        cout<< x;
    }
    // the_file is closed implicitly here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with this.

[Using argc and argv parameters](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/) or you can put all the inputs you want in a .txt file and [use < command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

I dont think you are looking for the second option, so try the first one, as far I know that is the only way to pass parameters to a program in C++

so your code should look something like this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    string name;
    if(argc == 1){
        cout << "Whoops, you need to put your name" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    name = argv[1]; 
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

argc in the numbers of parameters you're passing to main function and argv contain the parameters, ALWAYS there is at least one parameter, the name of the .exe itself, so if you're passing one parameter, in your case a name, argc is 2, if you're passing n parameters then argc is n+1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Boost Options library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html